# BigQuery / Google Merchant Center data transfer error - 'NOT_FOUND: Resource not found'

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm receiving a 'not_found' error when setting up a data transfer between google merchant center and big query.

> NOT_FOUND: Resource not found (resource=scheduler-merchant_center-REGION_EUROPE_WEST_1). [type.googleapis.com/util.MessageSetPayload='[google.rpc.error_details_ext] { message: "Resource not found (resource=scheduler-merchant_center-REGION_EUROPE_WEST_1)." details { [type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.DebugInfo] { detail: "Could not find in SpannerConfigStore: TopicByProjectIdAndName(project_id=XXXXXXXXX, topic_name=scheduler-merchant_center-REGION_EUROPE_WEST_1)" } } }']The data source might not be supported in the related region. And make sure the transfer run Pub/Sub topic has not been deleted in the data source owner project.

Nothing in the set up of the transfer mentioned setting up a Pub/Sub topic so not sure how to solve this?

I've followed all the steps here https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/merchant-center-transfer

- we've got sufficient permissions for big query and google merchant center
- waited more than 24 hours as specified
- we're in a supported region, the UK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I ran through an internal documentation regarding **Google Merchant Center**, these are the supported regions: `us`,`eu`,`asia-northeast1`,`asia-southeast1`,`australia-southeast1`,`europe-north1`,`europe-west2`, `europe-west6`, `us-east4`.

You need to add [Pub/Sub topics & subscriptions](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/create-topic) used by Google Merchant Center for your region.

Comment: Thanks Poala, changing the BigQuery dataset to 'europe-west2' worked. Where is this in the documentation? I wasn't able to see it, would be useful to provide a link to where it can be found for anyone else with the same issue - Thanks!

Comment: Hi, if you have access in buganizer, you can search through the filed bug issues and view it there. I can't provide the link here, my bad.